# Implicit declaration of function 'put_user' is invalid in C99 though include "linux/uaccess.h" in clion

Tags: c, compiler-errors, linux-kernel, driver, clion

I try to use put_user in clion and I get

```
Implicit declaration of function 'get_user' is invalid in C99
```

Minimal example:

```
#include "linux/uaccess.h"
static ssize_t device_write(struct file *file, const char __user *buffer, size_t length, loff_t *offset) {
char* priv_buffer='a';
get_user(priv_buffer[0], &buffer[0]);
}
```

sidenote: in the make I declared it as c11 prject.

Comment: Has the kernel source been configured so that the proper `<asm/uaccess.h>` is included by `<linux/uaccess.h>`?